# Best Version Control System for IIS?

Tags: version-control, cvs

I'm looking for a good VCS (Version Control System, eg. CVS) that runs on Windows or IIS5 (I have a webserver and see no reason to install Apache). Preferrably something with a Visual Studio integrated client, and preferrably free. Does such a beast exist or will I have to buy sourcesafe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather spend a couple of grand and run TFS, then use a free copy of source safe. Of course there are plenty of other cheaper alternatives out there (Subversion for example)

If you have a Team edition of Visual Studio you do get a free edition of TFS which will work for five users. Just a thought if have MSDN already.

Comment: Thanks, but I only have pro and this is for my personal projects. Now if I could afford a Universal subscription... :)

Comment: Come on it's only $2500 (over three years I think)! Im kidding...Well find a Microsoft Employee befriend them and ask for their friends discount that will bring it down some. Anyways I hear yea

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) which is free and doesn't require IIS or Apache.  Spent years on Sourcesafe but had nothing but trouble.

You can use the [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) client which is free.

For visual studio I use [VisualSvn](http://www.visualsvn.com/) who provide an integrated plug-in - but it's not free - only $50 though.

[AnkhSvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) do provide a free plugin though I believe.

Answer (score 4):

Subversion is pretty good, though I'm also a fan of DVCS systems (mercurial and GIT).  The big advantage of SVN is that its GUI tools are fairly mature.